# Angular Material 2 mat-form-field offset property in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, angular-material2

[screenshot in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkKog.png)
[screenshot in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYCl7.png)

Hi! I just insert the  tag in my project.
As you can see the first screenshot, I think there is a problem when rendering angular material mat-form-field element in IE 11.

I want it to be shown like the chrome one above screenshot.
In IE 11 there is an "offset(position) slip" of mat-form-field element's underline.

I have already inspected about it through developer console. And my conclusion is that in IE 11 there is something which affects the position(offset property in IE) of  element when I focus on that element.

below is the screenshot before I focus on the element.
[before focusing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gALyG.png)
after I focus,
[after focusing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W2jB.png)

How could I fix this problem :D??

Comment: What's your IE browser version and angular version? Based on [this sample](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview), I test it on my IE browser (v: 11.17134.1.0), it seems that everything works well. So, you could try to refresh the page, or upgrade the IE browser version to the latest version. If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I can not post my code because it is private code :(. I think I need to find the way to solve by myself. Sorry for asking  none-specific question to you. I will try my best next time I post my question to make my problem reproduced.